# Resetting PATH and PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, homebrew

I installed Python 3.5.1 through Homebrew on my Mac, and whenever I run `python`, or even `python3`, in Terminal, it raises this error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00007fff78ab9000 (most recent call first):
Abort trap: 6
```

I realize that this is probably due to Python 2.7 being run, instead of Python 3, and this must be due to an error in my `$PATH` because whenever I run `python --version`, the output is `Python 3.5.1`

`/usr/bin/python` is the executable, which I believe is version 2.7.

`/usr/local/bin/python3.5` is an Alias to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5`

This is `~/.bash_profile` file contents

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/Python:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-override:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.7/Python/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/cairo.framework/Versions/1/Python:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python26.zip:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python22.7.6/lib-tk:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Users/Sasha/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1:/Users/Sasha/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/PyQt-gpl-5.5.1
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
alias python="python3"
```

Comment: You put a lot of Python 2 libraries in your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Have you tried removing the `PHTHONPATH` in a `bash` window (`unset PYTHONPATH`) and run `python`?